# FormSet saves the data of only one form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When I submitted forms (but on page I filled id more than 1 form) - my FormSet saves the data of only one form, the rest of the data just disappear...

My template:

```
 <div id="data">
    <form method="post" action="/lookup/" id="test_data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <section id="test_data_row">
            {{ form }}
            </section>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</div>
<div class="bt">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_form" form="test_data">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add" value="Add row"/>Add row</button>
</div>
```

My forms.py:

```
class LookupForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = look
      exclude = ()
LookupFormSet = formset_factory(LookupForm, can_delete=True)
```

My model

```
class look(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'lookup'
    id_device = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number_country = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None)
```

my views.py:

```
def manage_articles(request):
   LookupFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=look, exclude=())
   if request.method == "POST":
      formset = LookupFormSet(
         request.POST, request.FILES,
         queryset=look.objects.none(),
      )
      if formset.is_valid():
         for form in formset:
             form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
   else:
      formset = LookupFormSet(queryset=look.objects.none())
   return render(request, 'req/lookup.html', {'formset': formset})
```

my JS (js for add new form):

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('test_data');
function duplicate() {
   var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
   clone.id = "test_data" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
   original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: You should be using [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory), not `formset_factory`.

Comment: @Alasdair, if I change my code 

from - 
`LookupFormSet = formset_factory(LookupForm)`

to:
`LookupFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=look, exclude=())`

all data from DB table are displayed on my page: http://take.ms/PRZl5 and I don't know why?!

Comment: It looks like half your comment is missing - what happens if you change your code?

Comment: @Alasdair my code below

Comment: @Alasdair Ok, thx. I've updated my code...
But as for now I have another problem - when I submitted my FormSet - data saves only from first form....the rest of the data just disappear...

Comment: First, make sure it works without JavaScript. Set `extra` to include multiple forms, e.g. `LookupFormSet(queryset=look.objects.none(), extra=3)`. Once that's working you need to debug your JavaScript. I can't really help you with this, but it looks like you are not updating the values in the management form when you add a new form. If you search for 'django dynamic formset' you should find other people's attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save a formset as it contains multiple forms. So I would suggest you change your code to:

```
   if formset.is_valid():
       for form in formset:
            form.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets).

Comment: It's solved my problem, but  I have a new problem.... Data is saved only from 1 form, other data is simply lost(

Comment: Did you pay attention to the indentation? Make sure the return call is on the level of the for loop.